# Delphi detecting local port of the Indy Client Component

Tags: delphi, indy

I need to know the local port of Indy TCP Client component during it is connecting with server.
As I read the manual, the BoundPort is local port of Indy Client component.
But this value always returns 0, not real local port.
Really BountPort indicates the local port of client component? And I took mistakes when getting it?
Or,any other good method of detecting the local port?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `TIdTCPClient.BoundPort` property is the port that YOU want the client to bind to locally. It is 0 by default, so the client can bind to whatever random port is available. Regardless of what the `BoundPort` is set to, the port that is actually bound to is available in the `TIdTCPClient.Socket.Binding.Port` property after the `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` method is successful.

Comment: It works well. Thank you very much from the bottom of my heart. Always you give me good way when I face troubles. But how can I vote your answer? it doesn't work.

Comment: @fangrenxing Voting is a privilege that you will get when you have 15 reps. [See details here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)